# How can I add product to cart programmatically in opencart verion 1.4.9.4

Tags: opencart2.x

I am customizing my clents store in opencart 1.4.9.4. I want to add a product dynamically to cart. I tried using

```
$this->cart->add($giftvoucher], $quantity, $option);
```

But it is not working

Comment: There's a syntax error, try removing the ']' from the code: `$this->cart->add($giftvoucher, $quantity, $option);`

Answer (score 0):

you have to check if there options or not
the easy way to do that using `ajax`
if you mean that you want `json` code this is it:

```
                $this->cart->add($this->request->post['product_id'], $quantity, $option, $recurring_id);
```

if you don't have `$recurring_id` just delete it